# Find words contain some letters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to search for specific letters in a word list and sort the words that contain those words.

The order of letters within a word is not important. I tried using this formula but it didn't work for me.

This screenshot shows what I mean:

[image]

This is the link to the file:

[Sheets link]](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ANmkZ6bnLcptPN4vdasBFt5K-ob-ET20nMa5-brxsAw/edit?usp=sharing)[Sheets link]

How can I correct this formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(A2:A,byrow(A2:A,lambda(Σ,sum(search(I3:K3,Σ)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add a customization so that the word does not contain letters other than the required letters (for example: this word "ones" will not appear)

Comment: then you could add an additional condition inside the *filter* formula (in addition to the exisitng *byrow* condition) such as `len(A2:A)=3`

Comment: But in this case, words containing repeated letters, such as "onen", will not appear, but I need them too.